# После ввода теста программа сразу заканчивается не выводя результат

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Задача:

> Удалить из матрицы А (6х9) все строки, содержащие единицы, передвинув на их место оставшиеся строки без нарушения порядка их следования.

После ввода теста программа сразу заканчивается не выводя результат (тот же массив с удалёнными строками, в которых были "1")

```
Тест:
2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Ожидал:
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int **A, t, ca;
   ca = 0;

   A = malloc(6 * sizeof(int *));
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       {A[i] = (int*)malloc(9 * sizeof(int));
       for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++)
           scanf("%d", &A[i][l]);}

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
       t = 0;
       for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++)
           if(A[i][l] = 1)
               t++;
       if (t != 0)
       {
           for(int j = i; j<6; j++)
               for (int k = 0; k<9; k++)
               {
                   A[j][k] = A[j+1][k];
                   ca++;
               }
       }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < (6-ca); i++)
       for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++)
       printf("%d", A[i][l]);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ca++;
```

-- это что делает? И чему равно `ca`, когда Вы его используете в `i < (6-ca)`?

---

Куда показывает `A[j+1]`, когда `j` равно `5`?

Comment: ca - счётчик срок, содержащих единицы. Нужен чтобы из 6 строк выводились только неудалённые. Про j = 5 я не подумал

Comment: @ФредфордПаркер Еще раз: чему равно `ca`, когда ...?

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял вопрос. "когда ...?" что?

Comment: @ФредфордПаркер когда Вы его используете в `i < (6-ca)`?

Comment: ca  равно количеству строк, содержащих единицы.

Comment: @ФредфордПаркер Я спрашиваю не "что Вы думаете по этому поводу", а какое у этой переменной значение на самом деле.

Comment: При данном тесте ca равно 2

Comment: @ФредфордПаркер Неправильный ответ. Как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: Простите, только сейчас понял, вы хотели чтобы я попробовал вывести ca, а не в уме считал

Comment: @ФредфордПаркер Можно и в уме. Главное, чтобы получался правильный ответ.

Comment: Перед циклом с (6-ca) я поставил вывод этого самого ca и оно ровнялось 135. Я вытащил ca++ за пределы for (int k = 0; k<9; k++) и программа начала выдавать ca = 6. Оставалось только if(A[i][l] = 1) переписать в if(A[i][l] == 1) и вот уже ca равнялось задуманным 2.

Comment: @ФредфордПаркер Я ничего не понял. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.